# If two balls are chosen at random and one of them is found to be of standard quality. What is the probability that the other one is defective?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

A football factory has two machines, A and B. Machine A manufactures 70% of the balls and machine B manufactures 30%. 80% of the balls from machine A and 90% of the balls from machine B are rated of standard quality.

Q1. A ball is chosen at random and is found to be of standard quality. What is the probability that it has come from machine A? The answer here is 0.67 and can be found using Bayes' rule.

Q2. If two balls manufactured using the same machine are chosen at random and one of them is found to be of standard quality, what is the probability that the other ball is defective?

My attempt:

I have used Bayes theorem to answer the question.

Here, D = event of having defective item, S = event of having  Standard quality item.

Pr(D|S) = Pr(D).Pr(S|D)/ Pr(S)

Pr(S) = 0.7*0.8 + 0.3*0.9 = 0.83
Pr(D) = 0.7*0.2 + 0.3*0.1 = 0.17

Since they are independent events. They have no common intersection between them, Pr(S|D) = Pr(S)

So, In my opinion, the answer is 0.17.

But, when I discussed this with my friends, one of them highlighted a point saying that "how do you know the exact first pick will be standard or defective?" In his opinion, I need to dig more. So it can happen in 4 ways. They are given below:

Event 1 could be One Standard, other is defective;
Event 2 could be One Defective, other is Standard; 
Event 3 could be Both Defective;
Event 4 could be both Standard.

I have used the conditional probability approach to solve that.

Now let's say X = event of other one is defective, Y = event of one of them is Standard

Pr(one of them being Standard) = 0.83*0.83 + 0.83*0.17 = 0.9711 (sum of event 1,2,4) ---> Pr(Y)

Pr(other one defective | one of them Standard) = Pr(X intersets Y) / P(Y)

Pr(X intersets Y) = 0.83*0.17 + 0.17*0.83 = 0.2822 (Sum of event 1,2)

therefore the answer is 0.2822/0.9711 = 0.2906

I have applied Bayes, got the same answer in this case.

which one was the correct approach? and if you could contrast between them, it will help me a lot to understand it better. TYIA

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing in the second approach at all.  $17\%$ of the balls are defective, so if a ball is chosen at random, the probability that it is defective is $.17$.  It doesn't matter that some other ball is standard.  The problem doesn't make much sense to me as given, since most of the information is extraneous.  Is it possible that we know that the two balls were produced by the same machine, but not which machine?

Comment: @saulspatz no. problem is assuming two machines producing balls but one machine has higher efficiency another one is less. that's how its constructed. I was thinking the same as yours. but the thing he pointed out, was bugging me a lot. The problem is we are choosing two balls at the same time.

Comment: In order for this type of question to make sense, there is usually something connecting the two samples (balls). Is the question perhaps that both balls were produced by the same machine? That would make the question more interesting. Otherwise, they really would appear to be independent and there is no reason to use conditional probabilities or Bayes' equation.

Comment: So what?  That isn't a problem.  Why should it be?

Comment: @Carl yes both balls are produced by the same machine

Comment: Okay, that changes the question completely. You should edit your post above to include that information. @Aurthur

Comment: If both balls were produced by the same machine, then the fact that the first ball is of standard quality provides some information about which machine produced it. Use Bayes' equation to estimate the probability that it was machine A or B and then use that result to estimate the probability that the second ball is defective.

Comment: @saulspatz I am confused, that's why wanted the clarification

Comment: @Arthur I guess so.  You told me the balls aren't necessarily produced by the same machine, and you told Carl they are.

Comment: @saulspatz this is exactly how the problem statement was given to me. Sorry if I made it ambiguous

Comment: @Carl yea, the problem has a previous part which is "A ball is chosen at random and is found to be of standard quality. What is the probability that it has come from machine A?" and the answer is 0.67 (used bayes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part of the question is ill-posed in two ways.  First, it is not clear whether the two balls were drawn from the same randomly selected machine.  Second, it is not clear whether the standard quality ball was determined by random selection and the second ball's quality is unknown, or if the quality of both balls is known to another party and you are told that at least one ball is of standard quality.  To illustrate why these things matter, consider the following scenarios:

1. The machines that make the balls dump them into a large bin, mixing up all of the balls; however, balls are stamped with a serial number that identifies which machine that made them.  You randomly select one ball from the bin, inspect it, and find it is of standard quality.  You then draw a second ball from the bin.  What is the probability it is defective?  The answer is $$1 - ((0.8)(0.7) + (0.9)(0.3)) = 0.17.$$
2. Same as Scenario 1, except this time, a factory worker randomly select two balls from the bin and inspects them.  Then he tells you that one of the balls is standard quality.  What is the probability the other ball is defective?  The answer is $$\frac{2(0.17)(0.83)}{1 - (0.17)^2} = \frac{34}{117} \approx 0.290598.$$
3. Now instead suppose the machines put the balls into separate bins.  The factory worker, with equal probability, selects one of the two bins, and randomly draws one ball for you to inspect; it is standard.  If he draws a second ball from the same bin (thus the same machine), what is the probability it is defective?  The answer is computed as follows.  Let $X_i = 1$ if ball $i$ is standard, and $0$ if defective.  Then the posterior probability of the worker having selected Bin $A$ given the $X_1 = 1$ is $$\Pr[A \mid X_1 = 1] = \frac{\Pr[X_1 = 1 \mid A]\Pr[A]}{\Pr[X_1 = 1]} = \frac{(0.8)(0.5)}{(0.8)(0.5)+(0.9)(0.5)} = \frac{8}{17} \approx 0.470588.$$  Consequently, the probability the second ball drawn from the same bin is defective is $$\begin{align*}
   \Pr[X_2 = 0 \mid X_1 = 1] &= \Pr[X_2 = 0 \mid A]\Pr[A \mid X_1 = 1] + \Pr[X_2 = 0 \mid B]\Pr[B \mid X_1 = 1] \\
   &= (0.2)(8/17) + (0.1)(9/17) = \frac{5}{34} \approx 0.147059.
   \end{align*}$$
4. As in Scenario 3, we have separate bins, but now this time, the factory worker selects a bin with probability proportional to the number of balls it contains; that is to say, because machine $A$ makes $70\%$ of the balls, he chooses bin $A$ with $70\%$ probability rather than $50\%$.  Everything else is the same.  Then the answer becomes $$(0.2)(56/83) + (0.1)(27/83) = \frac{139}{830} \approx 0.16747.$$
5. Now let's consider Scenario 3 except the factory worker has drawn two balls from the same bin, inspects them, and informs you that one of them is standard.  What is the probability the other is defective?  By now you should clearly realize that this probability will not be the same as **any** of the ones we have calculated so far.  I will not do the computation; I leave it as a straightforward exercise for the reader.
6. Consider Scenario 5 except now the probability of selecting a bin is as in Scenario 4.  Again, the computation will not be performed here and is left as an exercise.

As you can see, we must be **absolutely clear** about how the balls are drawn in order to perform the requisite computation.  The way the question is posed does not adequately describe the sampling scheme.

---

Now that the question has been rephrased, we can reasonably interpret it to match Scenario 3 or Scenario 4.  But which one is again not clear because it is not explained how two balls are randomly selected from the same machine.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing this confusion in such great detail.

Comment: would you mind explaining the 2nd scenario equation? How have you got that? I didn't understand why it is (0.17)^2 and the reason for placing 2.

Comment: @Aurthur The two balls drawn are essentially independent (if the bin is large enough).  So there are four outcomes, one of which is impossible (two defective balls).  The probability that there is at least one standard ball is $1 - (0.17)^2$.  The probability that there is **exactly** one standard ball (the other is defective) is $2(0.83)(0.17)$.